# CSS Responsive menu with h1 title (logo) centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

So I want to center a h1 without an image at the center of my navigation which has 2 more elements and it has to be responsive. I tried almost everything I can find but...works mostly with background images, and with inline-block I can't center it perfectly.

Below I have the best I could do, but hover doesn't work, probably cause of h1 width which 100%;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background-color: #232323;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -38px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#portofolio'>Portofolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a href='#/' class='logo'><h1>Tao SandBox</h1></a>
</header>
```

It has to be a better way!!!

http://codepen.io/taosx/pen/vNWojo?editors=110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyOKrN

Make the h1 use the .logo class. Then set absolute position and center it.

```
 .logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
   right:0;
   text-align:center;
 }
```

I'd also recommend adding the h1 markup prior to the nav, to maintain a better semantic flow.

```
    <header>

    <nav>
      <h1 class='logo'><a href='#/' >Tao SandBox</a></h1>
      <ul>
            <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href='#portofolio'>Portofolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Thank you! :D You the real mvp!

Comment: If you are worried about the background hover colors, you can work around that. My first stab at is was making the .logo a into display:block; then define the width, height and background color and use margin:0 auto; I just updated the codepen

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is just to make the logo` part of the menu like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #232323;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#/' class='logo'><h1>Tao SandBox</h1></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#portofolio'>Portofolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the h1 to be more flexible without disrupting the structure of the navbar. For example I want to bring it down just 10px so it's half outside the navigation, and add some css3 animations to it.

Comment: The you'll probably have to position it absolutely but it's probably not going to be terribly responsive as you'd have to hardcode some margins in there.